# iphone - how to make JSON data for NSMutableURLRequest GET Method

Tags: iphone, json, get, httprequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using JSONKit.h, JSONKit.m, ios5.1.

and I tried to send data using GET method and POST also but my django server gave errors.

Is my code wrong?

here is my codes.

```
NSString *myid = @"myidddd";
NSString *mypw = @"mypwwww";
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myid,mypw, nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id", @"pw", nil];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString *jsonInfo = [dic JSONString];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonInfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.scg.com:8000/post"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err){
    [self didReceiveData:data];
}];
```

Errors when my django server received the data,

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.send_preamble()
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
Traceback (most recent call last):
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54842)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in **init**
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in **init**
    self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

```
self.finish_response()
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54843)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in **init**
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in **init**
    self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

```
self.send_preamble()
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54844)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in **init**
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in **init**
    self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

### error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer.

The GET method can't contain data into http body. It is possible only use POST method.

To send some information with GET method, use extended request URL like:

```
"?%@=%@", key, value
```

Here is sample URL:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/?name=username&pw=password
```